# Struts2 validation doesn't work

Tags: struts2

I'm trying to validate a form using the Struts2 validator tool but it doesn't seem to work since, apparently, the xml validator is never acknowledged.

Here is my code:

struts.xml:

```
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="login_interceptor" class="org.apache.struts.gesprod.produccion.BLLogin">
    </interceptor>
    <interceptor-stack name="login_stack">
        <interceptor-ref name="login_interceptor" />
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    </interceptor-stack>
</interceptors>

<default-interceptor-ref name="login_stack"></default-interceptor-ref>

<global-results>
    <result name="input">/errores/error_input.jsp</result>
    <result name="error_sql">/errores/error_sql.jsp</result>
    <result name="no_logged">/login.jsp</result>
</global-results>
...
<action name="login" class="org.apache.struts.gesprod.produccion.BLUsuario" method="loginUsuario">
    <result name="success" type="redirect">/welcome.jsp</result>
    <result name="incorrecto_login">/login.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
</action>
```

login.jsp:

```
<div id="login">
    <s:fielderror />
    <s:form id="login_form" action="login" validate="true">
        <s:hidden name="intento_log" value="true" />
        <s:textfield name="usuario.username_usuario" label="Usuario"/>
        <s:password name="usuario.password_usuario" label="Password"/>
        <s:submit value="Ingresar"/>
    </s:form>
</div>
```

And the xml validator, placed in the same package as the Action class.

BLUsuario-login-validation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE validators PUBLIC 
    "-//OpenSymphony Group//XWork Validator 1.0.2//EN" 
    "http://www.opensymphony.com/xwork/xwork-validator-1.0.2.dtd">
<validators>
    <field name="usuario.username_usuario">
        <field-validator type="requiredstring">
            <message>Show error!</message>
        </field-validator>
    </field>
</validators>
```

Can somebody help and notice if there's something wrong with my code?

Comment: Well for one, I notice that you have the "input" result mapped globally.  This could be part of your problem.  When the validation is executed and it fails, it will return a result of input.  So, if you want to display the field errors in the login.jsp, then you need to map the input result to that JSP for the login action.

Comment: @rees Thank you, i did what you suggested and, granted, it should stay that way. But it still doesn't perform the validation, as if the "input" result is never returned even if the fields are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the name of the xml validator. You have to rename the validator with `login-validation.xml`. The name that you can put to your xml validator files are:

> Validation rules can be specified:
>
> **Per Action class:** in a file named ActionName-validation.xml
>
> **Per Action alias:** in a file named ActionName-alias-validation.xml
>
> **Inheritance hierarchy and interfaces implemented by Action class:** XWork searches up the inheritance tree of the action to find default validations for parent classes of the Action and interfaces implemented

You can see more here:
http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/validation.html#Validation-DefiningValidationRules

P.D: You said that "*the "input" result is never returned even if the fields are wrong*". The input result is returned if there are any field error (unless you specify other thing).

Comment: I meant the input result wasn't returned if the fields were wrong regarding what I specified in my custom validation. If I put, for instance, a String where an int is expected, of course the result is 'Input'.

Comment: Many thanks for the help but that didn't work either. Is there a way I can debug the validation interceptor?

Comment: I don't know. Can you edit your question with what you have now? Are you using the simple theme? If you put `<s:fielderror/>` tag in the jsp, does appear any error? Have you declared any interceptor?

Comment: Done. I'm using the default theme provided by Struts2. The form is rendered within a "wwFormTable" class div. As for the <s:fielderror/>, it's working because it's loading the scripts it's supposed to. I'll add my stack of interceptors to the question too.

Comment: If you delete the validation on the client, do the field errors display in the jsp? P.D: This line in `global-results` has no sense: `<result name="input">/errores/error_input.jsp</result>`.

Comment: The field errors doesn't display because it doesn't even return to the login.jsp because the validation was performed. It does it because, obviously, the username doesn't exist, so it perform the "incorrecto_login" result.

Comment: Are the parameters being captured in the `BLUsuario` action?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13480/discussion-between-iamsosick-and-daniel-calderon-mori)